# Use VBA in Excel 2013 to mimic moving using arrow keys

Tags: excel, vba, cursor, selection

I want to create a VBA macro for Excel 2013 to move the cursor. I am simply re-mapping keyboard shortcuts, e.g. I want to move the cursor down using CTRL+J instead of the down arrow. So I don't need anything fancy, just a simple cursor move. I also want to do this in VBA, so I'm not looking for, e.g., an Excel plugin or add-in or anything like that.

If, under the "Developer" tab, I select "Use Relative References", and then simply record a macro moving the cursor down, I get the following, which *does* move the cursor:

```
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1").Select
```

However, this is not a complete mimic of the down arrow. This subroutine/macro will move into hidden rows, which I do not want.

Each of the following give me an "Object doesn't support this property or method" error:

```
Selection.MoveDown Unit:=xlCell, Count:=1, Extend:=xlMove
...
Selection.MoveDown Unit:=xlWorksheetCell, Count:=1, Extend:=xlMove
...
Selection.MoveDown xlCell, 1, xlMove
...
Selection.MoveDown xlWorksheetCell, 1, xlMove
```

The following gives me a syntax error:

```
Selection.MoveDown(xlWorksheetCell, 1, xlMove)
```

I can imagine a moderatelymacro that moves the cursor, checks whether the new cell is hidden and, if so, repeats until it is not. However, I have a hard time believing that there isn't a command/method/etc that doesn't simply and easily mimic moving the cursor the way the arrow key does,ignoring hidden rows/columns. For example, I *can* mimic using the arrow keys while holding down the control key using, g., `Selection.End(xlDown).Select`. So I want to just mimic moving the cursor with an arrow key as simply as possible.

*(This seems like such a simple problem that I'm guessing someone has asked/answered this before. However, if so, and if you mark my question as a duplicate, please indicate where the original answer is, as I've looked and can't find it.)*

Comment: Remember touching the <kbd>DOWNARROW</kbd> only moves the `ActiveCell` down, not all of `Selection`

Comment: Thanks. I don't need to move the active cell starting from a complicated selection (e.g. several selected cells). I'll assume I'm starting from a single selected cell and then just want to mimic moving the active cell as if I've used an arrow key.

Comment: Lets look at SendKeys

Comment: check my answer below

Comment: Using `SendKeys` is generally warned against, but there are certainly applications for it.  However, more broadly, *why* do you want the cell selection to change on a shortcut?  Is it to run a macro, after the selection is changed? This might be an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: @BruceWayne Just checked your link...perhaps this _is_ an XY problem. My motivation: I want selection movement without moving my hands from their default position over the keyboard, i.e. I don't want to move my hands to the arrow keys. That's it. I don't know how to re-assign standard keyboard functions (like the arrow keys) in Excel without using macros. So I've been trying to solve this with VBA. I say I don't want plugins or add-ins because I also just want to get VBA to do what I want, but if you know of a more appropriate solution to my problem, I'm listening.

Comment: So, basically, you are looking to navigate your worksheet *without* using arrow keys? Any particular reason (i.e. could a different keyboard fix the reach for the arrow keys), or is there a technical reason you're avoiding them?

Comment: Simply keyboard ergonomics. I've used various other tools in the past for remapping things like simple cursor movements, and I know that I _love_ using, say, H/J/K/L with various modifier keys for left, down, up and right. Really speeds up my work if I don't have to constantly move my whole arm. In some circles, the H/J/K/L combo is kind of a standard. So I don't think a different keyboard would solve my problem.

Comment: Anything in [this reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/excel/comments/6bnpw2/a_little_program_that_helped_me_tons_with_excel/) help?  Or this [github](https://github.com/kjnh10/ExcelLikeVim) project?  And I haven't used it personally, but hear good things about [AutoHotkey](https://autohotkey.com/), which some threads have also suggested in using for `HJKL` movement in Excel.

Comment: Those look interesting, and I'll investigate further. However, once upon a time I had also found a (different) generic tool I could use for all my cursor movements in all programs, and I loved it...and then it stopped working after an OS update. So I'm a little hesitant to try other (non-Excel) tools. Furthermore, I'm working on a Mac running Parallels running Windows running Excel, so Windows-based tools like AutoHotKey etc make me quite nervous. Thanks for the suggestions though. The more complicated the VBA solution looks, the more interesting those other suggestions look.

Comment: I'm thinking Autohotkey might be a good option. You can use SendInput to mirror the keyboard button press. Getting WinAPIs working in VBA is a pain. Example AHK that works. `#ifWinActive, ahk_Class XLMAIN
^j::
 SendInput, {DOWN}
 return
;Turn off Conditional
#IfWinActive` You can use Post/SendMessage to send `DOWN` too.

Answer (score 2):

Assign your shortcut keys to:

```
Sub MoveDown()
    Application.SendKeys "{DOWN}"
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: If I assign this macro to "CTRL+J", this will now move my cursor down and it will skip over hidden rows as desired. However, for it to work a second time, I need to lift my finger off both the CTRL and J keys before pressing them both again instead of allowing me to continue holding down the CTRL key and just re-pressing the J key. When I use `ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1").Select` it moves the cursor but inappropriately moves into hidden rows, as I indicated in my question but at least it doesn't require me to un-press the CTRL key each time. Thus I'm still hoping for a better solution.

Comment: Very smart Gary! :)

Comment: @AndrewWillems Holding the CTRL key down will NOT work.  This is because Excel needs distinct combo-keystrokes to trigger the macro!!

Comment: My apologies, but I don't understand your comment. When my macro uses `ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1").Select` I do use CTRL+J just fine, i.e. I press the CTRL key a single time, press J ten times, and the active cell will move down ten times. I would like to reproduce that responsiveness to my keystrokes except ignoring hidden rows.

Comment: @AndrewWillems  I did not explain clearly....my previous comment concerned using CNTRL-j to trigger my macro...........sorry

Comment: @AndrewWillems  Clearly if you just keep DOWNARROW depressed, the activecell will rapidly move down the column...................my macro approach cannot replicate that behavior.

Comment: Gary'sStudent the use of sendkeys appears not only to select the cell but to activate it also.  While the original code only selects and thus the release of the ctrl is not required with the first but is with yours.  As to how to get around it.....IDK.

Answer (score 2):

**This was initially written as a solution, but I've since discovered it also has problems. I'll leave it because others have already commented, but note that it is *not* a solution (at least not in its current form).**

I found another web site [here](https://www.pcreview.co.uk/threads/move-cursor-down-skipping-hidden-rows.998950/) that answers my exact question. Here is the solution proposed:

```
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Range( _
  Cells(ActiveCell.Row + 1, ActiveCell.Column), _
  Cells(Rows.Count, ActiveCell.Column) _
)
rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells(1).Select
```

However, upon closer examination, this *does* work for moving down, but does *not* work for moving up. Specifically, you can move down past hidden rows, but it you try to move up past hidden rows the upward movement stops.

For Upwards:

```
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Range( _
  Cells(1, ActiveCell.Column), _
  Cells(ActiveCell.Row - 1, ActiveCell.Column) _
)
Dim rw As Long
rw = rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Areas( _
    rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Areas.Count _
    ).Row + rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Areas( _
    rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Areas.Count).Rows.Count - 1
rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells(rw).Select
```

Right:

```
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Range( _
  Cells(ActiveCell.Row, ActiveCell.Column + 1), _
  Cells(ActiveCell.Row, Columns.Count) _
)
rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells(1).Select
```

Left:

```
Set rng = Range( _
  Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 1), _
  Cells(ActiveCell.Row, ActiveCell.Column - 1) _
)
Dim rw As Long
rw = rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Areas( _
    rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Areas.Count _
    ).Column + rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Areas( _
    rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Areas.Count).Columns.Count - 1
rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells(rw).Select
```

I'm going to continue to work on this, but because this is my own answer to my own question, if someone else (who knows more about VBA than I do) wants to take this solution and modify it successfully in your own answer, you have my full blessings to do so.

Note also that even for the successful downward movement this solution produces an "Overflow" error if the row number is greater than 32766.

Comment: I do not get the overflow error I tested with row 1048562 and it moves down like it should.

Comment: If you are getting an overflow it is in how you are using it, which leads me to believe that @BruceWaynes comment is correct.

Comment: The overflow error may be due to my exact setup, i.e. using Excel 2013 in Windows 7 run on Parallels Desktop 13 for Mac. However, if the overflow error were the only problem, I'd probably just use this. However, my more recent edit to this solution discusses other bigger (but potentially solveable?!) problems with this solution.

Comment: I have a solution for up, I do not want to make my own answer as it is just an addition to yours, do you mind if I edit and add to yours?

Comment: If your solution to "up" is successful, that is great. Just know that I haven't yet tested "left" and "right", and I obviously need those to work as well. Also note that I don't mind you editing my solution, but I don't think you'll get credit for the answer then. If you want to copy from mine into your own, that's fine with me as well.

Comment: Left and right will just be modifications to the up and down, respectively.

Comment: This is getting much closer. It skips hidden cells nicely. It moves essentially as quickly as with arrow keys. However, there are lingering problems: Moving up from the second row to the first row causes a bizarre jump to somewhere else. Moving left produces bizarre jumps every time.

Comment: You will need to create checks for when the cursor is near the extents of the sheet, to deal with it so it does not do that, this is why I did not create my own answer.  I knew this was going to require a lot of work for the fringe elements.

Comment: I have fixed the Left, but you will notice the same problems when you get to the last two columns.  you will need to use `If then` statement to test for those columns to deal with the errors.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. I'll look into those edge cases.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what you're really going for, but what about this?

```
Option Explicit

Sub move_right()
NextVisible "Right"
End Sub

Sub move_left()
NextVisible "Left"
End Sub

Sub move_up()
NextVisible "Up"
End Sub

Sub move_down()
NextVisible "Down"
End Sub

Private Sub NextVisible(direction As String)
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.EnableEvents = False

Dim i As Long
Dim r As Range
Set r = ActiveCell
For i = 1 To Rows.Count
    On Error Resume Next 'If you're in A1 and try to go up one, it'll error. This skips that error.
    Select Case direction
        Case "Up"
            Set r = r.Offset(-1, 0)
        Case "Down"
            Set r = r.Offset(1, 0)
        Case "Left"
            Set r = r.Offset(0, -1)
        Case "Right"
            Set r = r.Offset(0, 1)
        Case Else
            Set r = r
    End Select
    On Error Goto 0

    If r.EntireRow.Hidden = False And r.EntireColumn.Hidden = False Then
        r.Select
        Exit Sub
    End If
Next i

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Then, simply assign a shortcut to each one...

[image]

So, pressing <kbd>CTRL+I</kbd> moves the active cell up.

Comment: The problem is that these do not skip non visible rows/columns, which is what the OP is after.

Comment: @ScottCraner - Ah, whoops.  Edited.

Comment: This works. However, if I have hidden 1000 rows and I'm now trying to move down past them, it takes almost a full 2 seconds for me to move down that "one" row. In contrast, the partial solution I posted in a different answer essentially moves instantaneously past the hidden rows.

Comment: @AndrewWillems - See my edit. This went from row 3, skipped 2000 hidden rows, then selected the next cell in less than a second.

Comment: Again, it works. However, it slows down the regular cursor movement, i.e. when hidden rows aren't an issue. For example, normal arrow key movement can go down 290 rows in 10 seconds, while with this code it can only go down 80 rows in 10 seconds. I'm not nitpicking: (1) I move the cursor constantly, so delays like this would drive me mad. (2) The other solution I posted does not seem to have this delay. I think the fact that it requires VBA-based looping (as opposed to, say, native looping in the Excel code itself, accessed by things like `rng.SpecialCells...`) makes this less useable.

Comment: @AndrewWillems - How much data do you have? I'm able to skip 10,000 rows in a second...  Edit: See [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YX37S.gif) showing a "Down" move. I have data from `A4:A9256` in there.

Comment: I'm not talking about skipping rows. I'm talking about just moving simply from one non-hidden cell to the next, e.g. from cell J12 to J13. I'm referring to how it takes to do that 10,000 times versus how long it takes to do the same thing using the arrow key.

Comment: @AndrewWillems - Maybe I'm still not understanding something...when I run the above, it works in a second at most, even if it has to skip 10,000 rows or columns.

Answer (score -1):

To move one cell down, provided there is no filter applied where rows are hidden.

```
Selection.End(xlDown).Select
Selection.End(xlUp).Offset(1).Select
```